# Что делать, если не отображается иконка на экране запущенных приложений?

Tags: android, иконки

На главном экране всё нормально отображается.
[image: Скрин]

Но на экране запущенных приложений что-то идет не так.
[image: Скрин]

Пробовал вставлять иконку и в android:icon, и в android:logo, но не помогает.

Comment: Иконку делали через [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio#access)?

Comment: Сделайте Clean/rebuild, посмотрите какая выставлена иконка в манифесте. RoundIcon или Icon. Скорее всего icon стоит дефолтная а на значке сеттится roundIcon

Comment: А после всех выше манипуляций удалите приложение, перезагрузите устройство и установите его заново. Кстати, у вас все значки ромбовидные или это ваша реализация для вашего приложения?

Answer (score 0):

Я решил данную проблему убрав из AndroidManifest.xml строчку android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" из раздела application.
Додумался это сделать, когда почитал официальную документацию и понял, что такого параметра нет в описании манифеста. Вот ссылка: 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element?hl=ru